# Python append multiple values to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I worked my way through multiple sites to try to figure this out but I'm at a loss.

My program needs to print a student name (found using input), class name (found using input) and then finally their final 3 scores. I can't find a way to append the scores to a dictionary through any site it all just gives me errors.

*Sorry for huge code snippet just thought it might be needed.*

```
import random
import operator
import time

end = False

scores = dict()

def randCalc():
    operators = {"+":operator.add,
                 "-":operator.sub,
                 "*":operator.mul}

    num1 = random.randint(1,10)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    op = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))
    answer = operators.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print("What is {} {} {}?\n".format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer

def askQuest():
    answer = randCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    guess = float(guess)
    return guess == answer

def quiz():
    print("WELCOME TO THE MATH QUIZ\n")
    global student
    student = input("What is your name? ")
    global classname
    classname = input("Which class are you in? (1, 2, 3) ")
    global score
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuest()
        if correct:
            score += 1
            print("Correct!\n")
        else:
          print("Incorrect!\n")
    classSelect()

while end == False:
    time.sleep(2)
    quiz()
```

Comment: Why should scores be the key? Shouldn't the names be the keys and the grades be the values?

Comment: Have you made any coding attempts at creating the dict you describe?

Comment: @naltipar Forgive me I correct the mistake after I checked the post.

Comment: @Totem Multiple including a few friends of mine who are also learning Python and we all couldn't figure out even when researching most methods we found kept bringing up errors with the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Idk if I am understanding you, but you can try using json(same as dict()) and have:

```
quizScores={}
quizScores[score1]=name;#score1 is score of first quiz
quizScores[score2]=name;#score2 is score of first quiz
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see why you would want `score` to be the key. Each key must be unique, having score as the key therefore only makes sense if you want to store an array of students with each score. If your problem is storing multiple values per key, you can store an array:

```
d = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}
print d["b"] # will print [4, 5, 6]
```

If you for some reason need to search by the values later, you can perform a linear search through the key/value pairs in the dict:

```
d = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}
search_array = [1,2,3]
for key, value in d.iteritems():
  if value == search_array:
    print key # will print a
```

Comment: Sorry about that I fixed the mistake I made. I understood how to print and start an array I already know but I'm trying to extend the variables to it. The key would be "Student + Classname" and then it would have his scores after it.

Comment: If the name and the class together are guaranteed to uniquely identify a student, can you not just store the concatenation of name and class? E.g.: "mark3"

Comment: Yeah that what I want to do so after they finish the quiz it adds {"Name + Class" : [Score1,Score2,Score3]} I'm not sure if its possible but I want to overwrite scores after it reaches 3 I'm guessing it would work with a range loop.